# Create ImageView depending on a varaible in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, imageview

I have an ImageView that shows the flag of a country depending on the nationality of a person.
At the moment I do that with a Switch-Case statement like that:

```
public in getFlag() {
        switch (nationality) {
        case "GER":
            return R.drawable.ger;
        case "AUS":
            return R.drawable.aus;
        case "FRA":
            return R.drawable.fra;
    }
}
```

But there are more countries than 3.. So I have to add a case-statement for each nationality.
is there an better opportunity for this.. more like:

```
imgFlag.setImageResource(R.drawable.(participants.getNationality());
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method returns a resource id according to a string:

```
public static int getResId(String resName, Class<?> c) {

    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

You should have now:

```
int resourceId = getResId(nationality.toLowerCase(), YourCurrentActivity.this.getClass());
imgFlag.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the method getResId needs a String and Class<?>. But when I getResId(nationality.toLowerCase()); I only passing a String.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the second argument, try this : 
int resourceId = getResId(nationality.toLowerCase()), YourCurrentActivity.this.getClass());

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner .. 
Now I get a Fatal Exception
Android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff

Comment: First make sure your drawable exists in your resource folder, then you should check if the string you put in parameter is not null, well spelled, matching with an existing resource, etc.. Because actually you are getting an error in the getResId method and the "catch" block returns "-1" as ID, which is not existing I guess.

Comment: I have checked all nationality strings and resource names. But there is still this error message.

Answer (score 0):

With reflections

```
try {
  Field field = R.drawable.class.getField(participants.getNationality().toLowerCase());
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
  if(field != null)
    imgFlag.setImageResource(field.getInt(null));
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```